# rygel and tracker-extract-3 load one cpu thread on 100%

Tags: cpu-load

I'm worried about these two processes because they cause my water cooling to work almost at maximum, and it is very noisy. The system was not modified in any way except for installing a vlc, pass, flatpack, openssh-server.

OS: Ubuntu 23.10
Kernel: 6.5.0-15-generic
Session: Wayland
GPU: rx6700xt
CPU: Ryzen 9 7950x

Results of `htop`:

[image]

Results of `journalctl`:

[image]

Results of `flatpak lis`t:

[image]

gnome-extensions:

[image]

Comment: 'rygel' is a media server, did you enable/install a media server? Serving video is always going to be resource-intensive, that's just how it is.

Comment: as for 'tracker-extract-3', there's a bug where it uses too much CPU. It is what enables Gnome search, so you'd lose out on that if you disable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tracker-miners/+bug/2025523) where `tracker-extract-3`, part of Ubuntu's file indexing (`tracker` package), uses excessive CPU. If you don't need file indexing, you can disable the Tracker package completely by masking its systemd service:

```
systemctl --user mask tracker-extract-3.service tracker-miner-fs-3.service tracker-miner-rss-3.service tracker-writeback-3.service tracker-xdg-portal-3.service tracker-miner-fs-control-3.service
```

then reset tracker with

```
tracker3 reset -s -r
```

and reboot. Those processes will be gone, but so will the search ability, full-text search in Files, and possibly other apps' functioning. If something isn't working properly and you want Tracker back, run

```
 systemctl --user unmask tracker-extract-3.service tracker-miner-fs-3.service tracker-miner-rss-3.service tracker-writeback-3.service tracker-xdg-portal-3.service tracker-miner-fs-control-3.service
```

to re-enable it.

[From [linuxuprising.com](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/how-to-completely-disable-tracker.html)]

As for the `rygel` process, it's a media server built in to Ubuntu. If you're not using it, you can uninstall with

```
sudo apt remove rygel
```